# "There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message" when consuming WCF web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I've seen several questions about this, but they all seem to be from the perspective of someone hosting a web service. In my case, I am the consumer only to a web service being provided by another company that I don't have access/control over.

Basically the other company is hosting a WCF web service that has two methods that I need to call. I added the service reference to a c# console application using the URL/WSDL and it generated the necessary classes. So far, so good.

But when I call either of the methods via my app, it comes back with a **"There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message"** and the inner exception says **"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."**

When I checked the WSDL, I noticed there is no 'bindings' section and indeed no binding details have been automatically generated in my app.config. When I've consumed web services in the past, I've never had to worry about this part, so I'm not sure if it's normal.

**So, my question is:** Is this an error on the other companies part and do they have to provide this information to me, or is this something I should be able to configure from my end?

Comment: Double check your spelling of parameters. It is likely that the route being requested will return not found if  a parameter is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: I didn't really need to spell the parameters, or anything else. The classes and methods are all generated by importing to WSDL in Visual Studio so I didn't have anywhere to make a simple typo.

Comment: If you are using the generated client proxy class then it should have been created using the latest metadata-exchange published for the service. I would say there is nothing you can do on your end, it has to be addressed on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

IIS server, hosting WCF service, filter incoming requests against some criteria's and reject request with a 404 Not found error page if some validation fail.

For example IIS will reject request with 404 not found page if request size is more than ~28.6MB (default value) or configured limit ([reference](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits)).

You can check your call against some of the default limits and then can ask company for more details.